# MySql Match() Against in Boolean mode

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm not able to figure it out why this is not working.

Here is my query which works:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM
  `pages`
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('Visual*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 10;
```

and here is my pages table:

```
id    title    
===============================
1     About Us
2     Visual Data
```

but this one does not return any records:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM
  `pages`
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('About*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 10;
```

here is SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d264f2/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several important concepts when using full text search -- and the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) has more details.

One key concept is what defines a word.  That is not important here, but MySQL lets you specify the delimiters.

Another key concept is that only some words are indexed.  Two common reasons why words are not indexed are:

- They are too short (or I suppose too long, but that is unusual).
- They are in the stop words list.

The words in the stop words list are usually "filler" words -- such as "the", "otherwise", . . . and you might guess "about".

You can override the stop words list.  You will need to provide another stop words list (or none at all).  And then rebuild the index.